# Save attempt saves the field/column but not the value

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, q

I'm using Parse and server side Javascript. I want to save the number Total in my column duty as shown below.  This code saves the new column duty but it puts no values into it.  Total has a mix of truthy and falsy values (like 0 and NaN) as every Id doens't have a Total.

```
for (i = 0; i < Ids.length; i++){
Id = Ids[i];

var Total = Math.round(_.reduce(_.map(value[i], function (n) {
     return n.Partial
   }), function (memo, num) {
     return memo + num;
   }, 0) * 100) / 100;


Query.get(Id, {
 success: function (item) {
   item.set("duty", Total);
   Q.all(item.save());
  }
 })
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/kriskowal/q which is a promise library. I may be using it wrong . . .

Comment: OK, I could've guessed that, only I would have expected that you'd use Parse promises. And yes, unless `item.save()` returns an array you're using it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to refactor a little, (without fully understanding the meaning of the code).  It becomes much clearer when divided into logical parts.  Things that happen asynchronously are always divided into promise-returning functions.

It culminates in an array of `savePromises`, which can be run together with `saveAll`.

```
var savePromises = [];
_.each(Ids, function(objectId, index) {
    savePromises.push(setDuty(objectId, index));
});
Parse.Object.saveAll(savePromises);

// get an object with its id.  use its index to compute a duty
// return a promise to save the object
function setDuty(objectId, index) {
    return getObjectWithId(objectId).then(function(object) {
        object.set("duty", dutyValueForIndex(index));
        return object.save();
    });
}

// return a promise to get an object with its id
function getObjectWithId(objectId) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Table_Name_Goes_Here");
    return query.get(objectId);
}

// compute duty for a given index
function dutyValueForIndex(index) {
    var array = _.map(value[i], function(n) {
        return n.Partial
    });
    var sum = _.reduce(array, function(memo, num) { return memo+num; }, 0);
    return sum * 100 / 100;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just saw this now so I'll take a look and follow up

Comment: Thanks Danh, you're approach is inpecable. I got a little help in finding the error: Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError Do you know what to do with that?  I'm in express and at the top of this JS file I have var Parse = require('parse').Parse;
Parse.initialize("JS key", "Application Key", "Master Key");

Comment: UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError means the code is attempting to write a _User row while there's no User.  By default, the user table is setup so only a user can modify his or her own record.  Since this is cloud code, the quick way around this is Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey().  (see https://parse.com/questions/getting-usercannotbealteredwithoutsessionerror)

Comment: What if I want to do this server side instead of cloud code?

Comment: From parse's perspective, you're either in cloud code, or not.  A browser calling the sdk or another server calling the sdk are both clients as far as parse is concerned.  So the choices are: 1) cloud code and userMasterKey, 2) from anyplace else: 2.1) login as a user and modify only that user's row, or 2.2) change class level permissions on _User to allow public write.  But 2.2 is not recommended because any bad guy could cause mayhem by writing the user table.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be taking it to cloud code then.  Your solution is otherwise right on point though. Very thorough.